# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceSecret"] returns null in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I am trying to implement JSON Web Tokens Authentication in ASP.NET Web API and and Identity 2.1 from http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2

I have followed every step of this tutorial.

"ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceSecret"]" this line returns null

As i understand this line returns the server's secret.

So, what is the problem and what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have the setting in your config file.

Comment: Yeah oddly the tutorial doesn't include adding the appSetting into your config... weird.

Comment: Yes, but, can anyone tell me what will be the value of this audience secret?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the matching setting key in your `.config` file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AudienceSecret" value="Enter Value Here" /> 
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the link you've provided, it is "as:AudienceSecret". Just make sure if you are not doing any typo. It is returning null value as it is not finding the provided key and its respective value in the web.config file.